# Number of cycle subgraphs in Petersen's graph

Tags: graph-theory

> What is the number of cycle subgraphs in a Petersen's graph?

Is the only way to count the number of cycle subgraphs in a graph can only be done by brute force? I've counted the Petersen's graph cycle subgraphs by **brute force**, and found that:

There are no 3-cycle, 4-cycle, 7-cycle. But there are 5,6,8,9-cycles, with the following number:

> 5 vertices: 12 cycle subgraphs,

> 6 vertices: 10 6-cycle subgraphs

> 8 vertices: 10 8-cycle subgraphs

> 9 vertices: 10 9-cycle subgraphs

I'm not sure about my answer, and I was just wondering if there's a more elegant method of finding cycle subgraphs in Petersen's graph

By the way, anyone not knowing Petersen's graph, I have attached an image below:

[image: Petersen's graph]